# MVC2 Application Can we make a page where Input and display list in same place

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

[image]

I have code below two table first is display Input field and second is display list, problem is that in input field showing the collection which is bind with that.

Code for View

```
<h2>AddmissionCellWithModel</h2>

<div>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("InsertN", "AddmissionCell", FormMethod.Post))
       { %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Student's Name: 
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox("StudentName", Model)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                Addmission Year:
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox("AddmissionYear", Model)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Father's Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox("FatherName", Model)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                Mother's Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox("MotherName", Model)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Contact:
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Contact", Model)%>
            </td>
             <td>
                Address:
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Address", Model)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                SchoolName:
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox("SchoolName", Model)%>
            </td>
             <td>
                EnrollmentId:
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.TextBox("EnrollmentID", Model)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="right">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">



            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>



    <%} %>
</div>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            EnrollmentID
        </th>
        <th>
            StudentName
        </th>
        <th>
            SchoolName
        </th>
        <th>
            StudentID
        </th>
        <th>
            FatherName
        </th>
        <th>
            MotherName
        </th>
        <th>
            Address
        </th>
        <th>
            Contact
        </th>
        <th>
            ClassId
        </th>
        <th>
            AddmissionYear
        </th>
        <th>
            EnrollDateTime
        </th>
        <th>
            IsActive
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%: item.EnrollmentID %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.StudentName %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.SchoolName %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.StudentID %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.FatherName %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.MotherName %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.Address %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.Contact %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.ClassId %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.AddmissionYear %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.EnrollDateTime) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%: item.IsActive %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
```

and code for Controller...

public ActionResult AddmissionCellWithModel()
        {

```
        SchoolManagementV1Entities db = new SchoolManagementV1Entities();
        List<EnrollmentModel> result = (from q in db.VW_EnrollmentModel
                                        select new EnrollmentModel()
                                        {
                                            EnrollmentID = q.EnrollmentId,
                                            StudentName = q.StudentName,
                                            StudentID = q.StudentID,
                                            FatherName = q.FatherName,
                                            MotherName = q.MotherName,
                                            Address = q.Address,
                                            Contact = q.Contact ?? 0,
                                            AddmissionYear = q.EnrollYear,
                                            EnrollDateTime = q.AdmissionDateTime,
                                            IsActive = q.EnrollIsActive
                                        }).ToList();
        return View(result);
    }
```

this return view is return the result object to the view

so some on tell me how can prevent to display the System.Collection.Generic....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a single or multiple forms?

I'm asking this because in the image I see only 1 form but you are passing a list of EnrollmentModel.

If you need only 1 form and 1 table (I think this is your case), pass to View only EnrollmentModel, not a list of them.

So change this:

```
List<EnrollmentModel> result = (from q in db.VW_EnrollmentModel
                                    select new EnrollmentModel()
                                    {
                                        EnrollmentID = q.EnrollmentId,
                                        StudentName = q.StudentName,
                                        StudentID = q.StudentID,
                                        FatherName = q.FatherName,
                                        MotherName = q.MotherName,
                                        Address = q.Address,
                                        Contact = q.Contact ?? 0,
                                        AddmissionYear = q.EnrollYear,
                                        EnrollDateTime = q.AdmissionDateTime,
                                        IsActive = q.EnrollIsActive
                                    }).ToList();
    return View(result);
```

with something like this:

```
var myId=7; //Example
return View(db.VW_EnrollmentModel.Single(m=>m.EnrollmentId==myId));
```

Note that here I'm guessing your want to display a single VW_EnrollmentModel, retrieved using EnrollmentId.

You then have to change your view setting correct model type and properties: in fact now the model is VW_EnrollmentModel so you don't have AddmissionYear but EnrollYear for example.

If this is not the expected result add a comment and I'll edit my answer.

Hope this helps,

Alberto